# Rectangle can't be drawn on the panel by mouse dragging runtime

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, onpaint

I am trying to draw a rectangle on a panel, but nothing is drawn. Below is the code to show how I draw a rectangle on the panel. In my code `SetSelectionRect()` is used to set the rectangle to be drawn. For these I use following methods.

```
   private void Panel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        this.mouseDown = true;
        this.Panel.SendToBack();

        point = this.Panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        point.X = e.X;
        point.Y = e.Y;
        this.selectionStart.X = point.X;
        this.selectionStart.Y = point.Y;
    }

    private void Panel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.mouseDown)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            this.mouseMove = true;
            Point point = this.Panel.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            point.X = e.X;
            point.Y = e.Y;
            this.selectionEnd.X = point.X;
            this.selectionEnd.Y = point.Y;
            this.SetSelectionRect();
            ////this.Panel.Invalidate();
            ////this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void Panel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        SetSelectionRect();
        this.GetSelectedControls();
        this.mouseDown = false;
        this.mouseMove = false;
        ////this.Panel.Invalidate();
        ////this.Invalidate();
        this.Panel.Refresh();
    }

    private void Panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        ////base.OnPaint(e); drawRect = true when RectangleToolStripMenuItem is Clicked.
        if (this.drawRect)
        {
            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1F))
            {

                    this.rectangle = new RectangleShape();
                    this.Panel.SendToBack();
                    this.shapeContainer1.Shapes.Add(this.rectangle);
                    this.rectangle.Location = this.selection.Location;
                    this.rectangle.Size = this.selection.Size;
                    this.rectangle.Name = "rectShape";
                    this.shapeContainer1.Size = this.Panel.Size;
                    this.shapeContainer1.Location = this.Panel.Location;
                    this.rectangle.Enabled = false;
                    this.rectangle.MouseClick += new MouseEventHandler(this.mouseclick);
                    this.rectangle.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(this.mouseMove);
                    this.rectangle.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(this.mouseDown);
                    this.rectangle.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(this.mouseUp);
                    this.drawRect = false; 
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }
```

What's wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `base.OnPaint(e);` is raising an `Paint` event, where you placed `base.OnPaint(e);`, so it calling itself again and again.

```
private void panel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    //base.OnPaint(e); // remove it from here
    // something to do.
}
```

`base.OnPaint(e);` should be called in overriden method:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But the problem is I need base.OnPaint(e), because I have facility to add Rectangle shape in the panel runtime (by mouse dragging.) Without base.OnPaint(e), I can't draw shapes.

Comment: Use overriden method OnPaint, see my updated answer.

Comment: Great. One more thing. See edited question. THe rectangle doesn't drawn. Why so?

Comment: This should be a new question actually. It's quite hard to answer for this in comments. But in short the reason is you don't call `Invalidate` method. Method `OnPaint` is called when your form need to be redrawn, it is not happening when you just move the mouse over the form or click.

Comment: Should I `Invalidate` `Panel` or `Form`?

Comment: Tried both. But the same problem. Should I post the code for the panel. What I actually do is, drag mouse to draw a rectangle in the panel runtime. For that I use MouseUp, MouseMove, MouseDown, and Paint events. Should I post the code?

Comment: @DhavalR Yes, please.